# Fixing up a commit that happened before a merge

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase

Consider the following history

```
R--A--B--C------F--H--D'
 \             /
  -------- D--E
```

D' is a fixup for commit D, that I want to integrate in the history, but  `git rebase -i` doesn't let me do it.

I can recreate the history manually, by resetting to E, fixup, redo merge, and cherry-pick H, but it screws up commit dates and it is cumbersome.

How can I proceed?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your graphic. Where are the parent commits of D? Is the connection between E and F a merge?

Comment: Yes, F is a merge commit from C and E. Hope it's clearer with this edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this another time, and tried the `--preserve-merges` option to `git rebase -i`, it works perfectly.

No need to redo the merge manually!

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is probably what you said: reset, redo merge, cherry-pick H. To retain the old commit dates, you should be able to do something like this:

```
git merge --no-commit my-branch
git commit -C <sha of F>
git cherry-pick <sha of H>
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the magic behind `-C`? It copies meta-info from sha of F, right?

Comment: Also I don't understand why `git rebase -i` can't help me with this use case.

Comment: Yes, `-C` copies the commit message and author info (including timestamp) from the specified ref.

Comment: In short, rebase doesn't know how to modify history before a merge.

Comment: doesn't cherry-pick already take commit info from the original commit? in this case last to commands can be merged into `git cherry-pick --no-commit  <sha of H>`

Comment: So it does - for some reason I thought it overwrote the author timestamp, but it doesn't. Fixed...